# clipToBounds and masksToBounds performance issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have UIScrollView and number of objects (UIView compositions) with UIImageViews inside them. Some of UIImageViews has round border (I use `myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` for this). Other has rectangle borders and part of image in them (I use `Clip subviews` property in Interface Builder for this).

The issue is that I found that clip properties strongly affect the performance while scrolling:

For iPod touch (4th generation) results of profiling:

- with enabled clip properties (both or one of them) I have around 30 fps while scrolling
- with disabled clip properties I have all 60 fps while scrolling

I really need to clip some images to round bounds and other to rectangle bounds (to show part of image). So, here is my question: what ways there are to improve performance? May be there are low level ways to do it (`drawRect:` or something), or may be it would be useful to play around alfa masking or I just do something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you have graphically intensive masks and things, a simple and easy way to improve performance (often times dramatically) is to set `shouldRasterize` to `YES` on the layer for that item:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// ...

view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

This will rastersize the view into a buffer, so  it isn't constantly re-rendered. This will take up a extra memory for each view, so you should really try and recycle/reuse views as you scroll, similar to how a table view does.

For correct behaviour on retina display you also need to set an appropriate value for `rasterizationScale`:

```
view.layer.rasterizationScale = view.window.screen.scale; // or [UIScreen mainScreen]
```

I've had great success with this for things like scrolling photo galleries, where each item had rounded corners, shadows, etc.

Comment: good advice! but now it really helps when I apply this property to whole view (with rounded image view and text label inside). In this case text becomes so ugly.. If I apply it only on rounded image view it gets almost no effect.

Comment: Ah, sorry. For retina support, set `view.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`. That should make everything crisp. I've updated my answer.

Comment: And rememeber to check your memory usage. Use the "Activity Monitor" instrument to see the memory usage difference when you use rasterization. The extra video memory probably won't show up in Allocations. If the increase is too large you should try and recycle views like I said, so that there aren't too many instances at any single time.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is saving my bacon and allowing me to keep using nice rounded corners.